# Designing a fast algorithm which adds three numbers in array

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Given an array `A`, and a value called `value`. Does there exist three elements in `A` where their sum equals `value`?

Note that repeating elements are allowed. For example: I have an array `1 2 4 5` and value, 3.

`A[0] + A[0] + A[0] = 3`

---

I already created the naive brute-force `O(n^3)` algorithmic approach, but there appears to be a way through `reduction` to get this to `Θ(n^2*log n)` time (where log is in base two). My question is: How? I don't really see much way to improve this algorithm. (but then again I am new to this field).

Thanks in advance. I'd really appreciate any pointers or advice.

---

Thanks everyone for the help. I've designed version 2 of the algorithm!

```
answer = False
sort(A)
for i=1 to n
    for j=1 to n
        found = BinarySearch(t-A[i]+A[j])
        if found!=-1
            if (A[found]+A[i]+A[j])=value
                answer = True
return answer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can indeed be done in $O(n^2 \log n)$ time. Here's a rough sketch.

Firstly, sort the array using any of the comparison based sort algorithm (like Merge Sort, Quick Sort etc.), this will take $O(n \log n)$ time.

Then, by using 2 nested loops going over the array (which will take $O(n^2)$ time) for each combination. Now, calculate sum of elements for each combination. Call this value $s$. Now, search value $\text{required number} - s$ in the array in $O(\log n)$ time. If each binary search for all $n^2$ possibilities returns false, then no such 3 elements exist. Otherwise, you can stop when you get first 3-tuple or enlist all such tuples.

Thus, the algorithm will take $O(n \log n) + O(n^2 \log n) = O(n^2 \log n)$ time.

Comment: You can even use an inefficient sort as $O(n^2)$ will be absorbed in $O(n^2\log n)$ anyway.

Comment: Yes, true. But $O(n \log n)$ will be `faster'.

Comment: Makes more sense but why do we need to sort the array?

Comment: @user1008537: Ever heard of binary search ?

Comment: Err. Not yet, but I'll go check it out

Comment: Remember that binary search works only in the sorted arrays. It is what improves the search from $O(n)$ to $O(\log n)$, thereby improving the algorithm from $O(n^3)$ to $O(n^2 \log n)$.

Comment: @user1008537: in the same vein, you can use a hash table to store the array, which will lower the complexity to about $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Hash tables have worst-case time of $O(n)$, I suppose.

Comment: Yes but they will be... `faster'.

Comment: Omg, that made me LOL instantly! XD

Comment: I've updated my algorithm in the description. What are your guys' thoughts on it? I think I've done it correctly and it makes sense but it would be great to get another pair of eyes.

Comment: That seems correct. Incidentally, reading it and my answer again helped me fix a minor bug in my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Great, thanks a ton guys. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try all $N(N+1)/2$ pairs $(A[i], A[j])$ and look for $Value-A[i]-A[j]$ by dichotomic search in the array (sorted).