# Algorithm that adds three numbers in an array that performs in O(n^2) time

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Note that this question extends on this previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936624/designing-a-fast-algorithm-which-adds-three-numbers-in-array).

Given an array `A`, and a value called `value`. Does there exist three elements in `A` where their sum equals `value`?

Note that repeating elements are allowed. For example: I have an array `1 2 4 5` and value, 3.

`A[0] + A[0] + A[0] = 3`

---

I created the naive brute-force `O(n^3)` algorithmic approach by myself, and with help through another question, I was able to break it to `O(n^2log*n)` time...

But there appears to be a way to break this even further to `Θ(n^2)` time. To be honest, I really don't know how that is possible (for the record, I am a beginner at this stuff). Is there an algorithm such as BinarySearch that could be useful to us?

I'd really appreciate any tips, pointers, or advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up 3SUM.  This is a known (and well researched) problem.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I never knew about that.